# using Aldryn Apphooks Config

Tags: django

Hi everyone one I am using `Aldryn Apphooks Config` to add configuration to my apphook.

My model is like this

```
class Entry(models.Model):
  TYPES_CHOICES = ( 
    ('none', 'not specified'),
    ('v', 'By Visit'),
    ('p', 'By Patient'),
  )
  app_config = AppHookConfigField(FaqConfig)
  url = models.CharField(blank=True, default='', max_length=250)
  count = models.CharField(blank=True, default='', max_length=250)
  start = models.CharField(blank=True, default='', max_length=250)
  status = models.CharField(choices=TYPES_CHOICES, max_length=10)
```

and my view.py is like this

```
class IndexView(AppConfigMixin, generic.ListView):
    model = Entry
    template_name = 'faq/index.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(IndexView, self).get_queryset()
        return qs.namespace(self.namespace)

  def get_context_data (self, **kwargs): 
    context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    values_to_pass = context['object_list'].values('url', 'count', 'start')
    context['object_list'] = values_to_pass
    print context['object_list']
    return context
```

I add get_context_data to get the parameter, but in this case this return a empty list

If I return `print context` I obtain this

```
{u'paginator': <django.core.paginator.Paginator object at 0x112aeff90>, u'object_list': [], u'page_obj': <Page 1 of 1>, u'entry_list': [], u'is_paginated': False, u'view': <health.views.IndexView object at 0x1124d9f10>}
```

Any idea why `u'object_list` and `entry_list` is empty, How to get the parameters of my model `url`, `status` and `count`

Any idea how to do this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_context_data` method of `ListView` builds context to pass to html template. In order to change that, do the following.

```
class IndexView(AppConfigMixin, generic.ListView):
    model = Entry
    template_name = 'faq/index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MultipleObjectMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        values_to_pass = context['object_list'].values('url', 'count', 'start')
        context['new_object_list'] = values_to_pass
        return context
```

This will pass list of dicts to your html template like `[{'url': 'some_url', ....}, {...}, ....]`

Comment: Thanks @Adilet Maratov  I try to do that  `context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    values_to_pass = context['object_list'].values('url', 'count', 'start')
    context['object_list'] = values_to_pass` but this return a empty list [], any suggestion?

Comment: @Stone try to print `context['object_list']` right after the super function. See what it will show. If it prints objects you need, than do not override it, but add new key to the `context` add bundle required data there